# The relation of determinants between linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

[image: screenshot]

I am studying the simplicity of PSL and came across the above statement. I don't understand why $\det L_c =c \det L$? (Given two set of basis of the same vectorspace, $v_1,...v_n$ and $w_1,...w_n$, and a linear transformation $L $ sending $v_i$ to $w_i$, why does the determinant $L_c$ which send $v_i$ to $w_i$ except $v_n$ to $cw_n$)

Would anyone be able to explain it for me? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hint: Look at the matrices of $L^{-1}\cdot L_c$ and $L^{-1}\cdot L$ with respect to the basis $(v_i)_i$, and use that the determinant is multiplicative.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! so the matrix of $L^{-1} \cdot  L_{c}$ is diag{1,..1, c} and that of $L^{-1} \cdot L$ the identity matrix. Hence, $\det L^{-1}=( \det L)^{-1} = c( \det L_{c})^{-1}$, which gives $\det L_{c} =\det L$. Is that right?

Comment: Almost. You just forgot the "c" in your last equation ;-).

Comment: ah, right! Thank you.